# nested tables in aspose

Tags: c#, ms-word, aspose

I need to divide two cells in adjacent columns into X equal cells horizontally. I am given a `DocumentBuilder`, pointing to the cell. I decided that I can insert a separate table into the cell:

```
var table = builder.StartTable();

builder.InsertCell();

table.AutoFit(AutoFitBehavior.AutoFitToWindow);

builder.Write("1");
builder.EndRow();

builder.InsertCell();
builder.Write("2");
builder.EndRow();

builder.EndTable();
```

But still, there is a margin on the sides of the inner table:

[image](ignore the left cell being splitted by horizontal thick line)

I googled that `table.AutoFit(AutoFitBehavior.AutoFitToWindow);` should solve the problem, but it doesn't. What am I supposed to do, to get desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to split the cell vertically, by setting all other cells in a row `cell.CellFormat.VerticalMerge = CellMerge.First`, then adding X - 1 rows, in which cells are `cell.CellFormat.VerticalMerge = CellMerge.Previous`, except cells in columns to de divided.